# Simple question about htmlentities and a small editing on my code for better <img src> results

Tags: php, html-entities

I have a foreach loop (see below) that encodes the values to `htmlentities()` and then it is send through the form as a url. 
for example `www.domain.com/file.php?title=XXX&pics=XXX&content=XXX`

This is my code:

```
foreach($results as $image){
$encodedpics = '<img src="'.$image.'"><br>';
echo htmlentities($encodedpics, ENT_QUOTES);
```

Then in the submitted form, I decode using `html_entity_decode()` and appeared inside the textarea. The problem is that the url images appear like these and can not be displayed later.

```
<img src=\"http://www.mypic.jpg\">
<img alt=\"\" src=\"http://www.mypic.png\">
<img border=\"0\" src=\"http://mypic.jpg\">
```

My question is how can I have only a `<img src="www.mypic.jpg">` without `\` or borders or `alt`?
Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

run `htmlentities()` on `$image`, not the entire string.

```
foreach($results as $image){
$encodedpics = '<img src="'.htmlentities($image, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8).'"><br>';
echo $encodedpics;
```

Comment: Hello, thanks I didn't thought of that. I get a Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"' i guess for the 'utf-8. How can I fix that ?

Comment: My apologies, it should be 'UTF-8' (with quotes on both sides). the stack exchange gods don't consider adding a quote to correct a code example to be sufficient change.